# Is it possible to intercept stat calls on files in a Linux file system? (from userspace)

Tags: linux, system-calls

I'd like to intercept stat calls on a specific file and quickly perform an action ASAP once detected.

In the past I've used the INotify library but thats only worked for me when opening/writing/closing files etc. If I remember correctly, stat just reads the contents of the i-node on the file system so what would be the best way of intercepting the calls with a binary running in user space?

I guess this could also be generalized to intercepting system calls from userspace?

Also want to note that I do know the process I'm targeting but don't have any control over when it runs etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the technique is known as [function interposition](http://jayconrod.com/posts/23/tutorial-function-interposition-in-linux).

It works for applications that you start or control the start-up environment to be able to set `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the start-up environment and said binary runs under root whereas I run under a less privileged user with control over the file thats being stat'd upon. This makes this a lot more difficult and I'm starting to believe it's impossible without modifications to the kernel and build itself... Thanks for the link though, this technique seems useful in related work!

Comment: @AzeemIlyas In this case you cannot subvert other applications, it is a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use function hijacking at the library level with **LD_PRELOAD**, but this only works for dynamically linked binaries that are not setuid/setgid.  For static or setuid/setgid binaries you have to implement a kernel module to hijack the function at the kernel level.